# Fixando um view no Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Atualmente uso esse código pra colocar o Adview no Bottom, só que ao adicionar uma ScrollView, ele se fixa no final da lista e não no final da tela.

--

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/android" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="bosa" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btsair"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Sair" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="1357125518" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Josinaldo, inclua o xml do layout se puder, fica mais fácil entender a situação.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa um `ScrollView`, o uso do `match_parent` é diferente do que num `ViewGroup`.

Como [citado pelo **Romain Guy**](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/), um ex-desenvolvedor do AOSP, o `ScrollView` tem uma dinâmica diferente dos demais `ViewGroups` em relação ao conteúdo que está dentro.

Sem o uso da flag `fillViewPort`, é como se a regra de `layout_height` do `ScrollView` fosse sempre `wrap_content` independente da altura do conteúdo que está dentro.

Quando se usa o `fillViewPort="true"`, o `ScrollView` força com que a altura do primeiro filho (o único filho direto) seja `match_parent` em relação ao pai do `ScrollView`. Vou tentar explicar melhor com um exemplo.

Usando seu layout com a flag `fillViewPort="true"`, ficará:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"> <!-- Flag necessaria -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_ab" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="bosa" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btsair"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Sair" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="71684724/135" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Quando você não usa o `fillViewPort="true"`, já sabemos que o `RelativeLayout` ocupará o mínimo de altura necessária para conter o seu layout. Logo o seu `AdView` não irá para o fundo da tela.

Usando `fillViewPort="true"`, o `ScrollView` força que o `RelativeLayout` tenha altura `layout_height="match_parent"` em relação ao pai do `ScrollView`, que é o  `FrameLayout` da sua `Activity`.

Comment: tenho pouco conhecimento sobre layout, entendi passo a passo o que voce escreveu mais quando aplicado não me retornou mudança. (alterei o código com o scrollview dentro do relativo, creio que fique mais coerente..)

Comment: Ok, vou rever a solução com a mudança do layout.